# Updating a WCF .map file service reference

Tags: c#, wcf

Working on a system and need to update a WCF service. The issue I am having is that the service file is a .map file. Using Visual Studio I would have assumed that I could just right click it from solution explorer and update the service from there, but there is no such option.

The .map file itself is an xml containing the Service endpoints and what not. It is also grouped with (could be a plugin "VScommands" that did this grouping) a .cs file of the same name containing the auto-generated code to use the service.

I'm unsure what other information I should provide but if someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real late update, decided to just remove the entire service reference and re-add it.

Answer (score 0):

So to get around this issue I had to manually enter in the inforamtion I needed. Did this by using the svcutil.exe tool provided by microsoft.